# how to determine size of row in the database

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of varbinary field in SQL server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507785/size-of-varbinary-field-in-sql-server-2005)

In my SQL2005 database, I have a table that has a column varbinary(MAX).

How do I tell the size of the rows?  Or as an alternative, tell the size of the varbinary field in each row?

Comment: See the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507785/size-of-varbinary-field-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Example with link in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793022/how-to-come-to-limits-of-8060-bytes-per-row-and-8000-per-varchar-nvarchar-valu/3793265#3793265

Comment: thanks for the links. i was obviously searching for the wrong keywords. just need one more vote to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

There are two functions:

- [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) returns the size of the data (bytes)
- [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) returns the size of data (characters).

For a `varbinary(max)` column, you should use `DATALENGTH`:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(column) FROM Table;
```

Both functions return the *logical* value of the data, that is after all compression algorithms have been applied and the column is completely uncompressed. The actual number of bytes occupied on-disk cannot be determined, because is influenced by the various storage options, most importantly by the compression options ([row compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280576.aspx), [page compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464.aspx), [unicode compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835.aspx)) an by the [`large value types out of row`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173530.aspx) setting for the table.

Comment: So...is it possible to determine the size of the entire row, not just the one column (this was also kind of asked in the original question :)