# How to create the right condition for String.Length?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim ioStream As New MemoryStream(byteArray.Length)

If byteArray.Length = 78 Then
    ioStream.Write(byteArray, 78, byteArray.Length - 78)
Else
    ioStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length - 0)
End If
```

I want to create the condition to check (String.Length) for image from Northwind and image from My Files. but I didn't know how to create that. I have to try like above code but it didn't work.

Comment: To check the size in the database: [Size of VARBINARY field in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507785/size-of-varbinary-field-in-sql-server-2005). To get the size of a file: [FileInfo.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much, great information.. @AndrewMorton